# cURL using bash script with while read text file

Tags: bash, shell

Hi there anyone there having the same trouble like mine?
whenever I cURL the $list from the list.txt it just displaying {} which is a blank response from the API does my code should be really working properly or it is just a bug?
I know the $list is working because I can update the database status
Please this is a bit urgennnnttt :(

```
#! /bin/bash

filename=/var/lib/postgresql/Script/list.txt
database='dbname'
refLink='URL'
authorization='Authorization: Basic zxc'
expireDate=$(date -d "+3 days")
body="Message."

while IFS=' ' read -r list
do
        wow=$(curl --location --request POST $refLink \
        --header 'Authorization: Basic $authorization' \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --data-raw '{
        "title":"Expiration Notice",
        "body":"$body",
        "min" :[{"mobileNumber" : "$list"}],
        "type" : "Notification",
        "action_type" : "NotificationActivity"}')
        echo "result: '$result'"
        RESP=$(echo "$result" | grep -oP "^[^a-zA-Z0-9]")
        echo "RESP:'$RESP'"
        echo $body
        #echo $wow >> logs.txt
        psql -d $database -c "UPDATE tblname SET status='hehe' WHERE mobile='$list'"
done < $filename
```

Comment: can you show what `$list` looks like? It seems the mobileNumber line is likely to be flawed with those quotes? I am not seeing where `$result` gets defined?

Comment: the list looks like this

63278860015
63432423123

Comment: just 2 lines on the list 

63278860015 63432423123

Comment: result=$(curl --location --request POST $refLink \
        --header 'Authorization: Basic $authorization' \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --data-raw '{
        "title":"Expiration Notice",
        "body":"$body",
        "min" :[{"mobileNumber" : "$list"}],
        "type" : "Notification",
        "action_type" : "NotificationActivity"}')
        echo "result: '$result'"
        RESP=$(echo "$result" | grep -oP "^[^a-zA-Z0-9]")
        echo "RESP:'$RESP'"
        echo $body

Comment: the result is the curl sorry I forgot to change it

Comment: the response displays only {}instead of success

Comment: If I understand correctly, can you edit your question to change `wow` to `result`? Looks like the answer below by @Léa Gris is a good start at fixing some of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your `"$list"` JSON entry is not populated with the content of the `$list` variable because it is within single quotes of the `--data-raw` curl parameter.

What you need is compose your JSON data for the query before-hand, preferably with the help of `jq` or some other JSON processor, before sending it as argument to the `curl`'s `POST` request.

Multiple faults in your scripts (not exhaustive):

- Shebang is wrong with a space `#! /bin/bash`
- `expireDate=$(date -d "+3 days")` return date in locale format and this may not be what you need for your request.
- The request and the response data are not processed with JSON grammar aware tools. `grep` is not appropriate for JSON data.

Some clues but cannot fix your script more without knowing more about the API answers and functions you use.

Anyway here is how you can at least compose a proper JSON request:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename='/var/lib/postgresql/Script/list.txt'
database='dbname'
refLink='URL'
authorization='zxc'
expireDate=$(date -R -d "+3 days")
body="Message."

while IFS=' ' read -r list; do
  raw_json="$(
    jq -n --arg bdy "$body" --arg mobN "$list" \
    '.action_type="NotificationActivity"|.title="Expiration Notice"|.type="Notification"|.body=$bdy|.min[0].mobileNumber=$mobN|.'
  )"
  json_reply="$(curl --location --request POST "$refLink" \
    --header "Authorization: Basic $authorization" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw "$raw_json")"
  echo "json_reply: '$json_reply'"
  echo "$body"
#  psql -d "$database" -c "UPDATE tblname SET status='hehe' WHERE mobile='$list'"
done <"$filename"
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: I'm getting 400 Bad Request

Comment: thank you so much for your concern :) I will redo my script.